# How to use javascript in p:confirm message attribute

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm migrating a project from primefaces 4 to 6.1.

I've come across this snippet

```
<p:confirm message="Really delete user \''+getOtherCellTextInSameRow(this,'userName')+'\'?"
           header="Confirmation"
           icon="ui-icon-alert" />
```

The message in the resultant confirmation dialog appears exactly as above. The javascript method `getOtherCellTextInSameRow` is no longer being executed. How do I fix this? I think I'm asking how do you inject client side javascript into an attribute?

Note, closest I have found is to use EL but I don't wish to do that. I simply want to concatenate the output of the method.

Comment: I think the only solution is to look at the javascript code of this component and try to bind a 'onshow' eventhandler and in that eventhandler do what you want to do.

Comment: @Kukeltje can I ask why you replaced "confirm" with "confirmDialog" in the title? Are they the same? There is no p:confimDialog in the xhtml.

Comment: OOOOP Sorry misread this... Will revert.. My initial comment might need a revision to... **Sorry**